# CSS problems with dropdown

Tags: html, css

I got a problem when i hover over the home tab. The dropdown is getting behind USERNAME. I have tryed diffrent things but it have not worked. Also i havent found a post that explains this error.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPlXA.jpg

My CSS kode:

```
.dropdown-nav {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: .9em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown-nav:hover {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: .9em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #00A5F7;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.customnav li:hover  ul  {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;

}
.customnav li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #0088cc;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: -100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}
.dropdown-custom-ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 5px #696969;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<nav class="customnav">
    <li class="navtab">
    <a class="navtab-inside" href="index.php">Home &or;</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-custom-ul">
        <li><a class="dropdown-nav" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-nav" href="#">Need Help?</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-nav" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-nav" href="#">How It Works</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navtab">
    <a class="navtab-inside" href="#">Maps</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navtab">
    <a class="navtab-inside" href="#">Mods</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navtab">
    <a class="navtab-inside" href="#">Plugins</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navtab">
    <a class="navtab-inside" href="#">Texture Packs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navtab">
    <a class="navtab-inside" href="#">Sell a service</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navtab2">
    <a class="navtab-inside" href="#">Sign In</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navtab">
    <a class="navtab-inside navtab-inside-active" href="#">Join</a>
    </li>
</nav>


<form action="" class="box2" method="post">
<a class="join_firstline">Join with Password</a>
<div class="join input-group">
    <a class="join_topic">Username *</a>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="join input-group">
    <a class="join_topic">First Name *</a>
    <input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" value="" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: Add a `z-index` to `.customnav li ul` to bring it in front

Comment: Please narrow down the problem and create a jsFiddle out of it. The problem is most probably around z-index/absolute positionning, but narrowing it down might even help you finding the answer yourself.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/   .. Z-index can solve your problem ..

Comment: It's not what you asked but you don't have to repeat everything when you want to change a property on hover. 
In your code:
.dropdown-nav:hover{background-color: #00A5F7;border-radius: 4px;} would do as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *This is a self-answer moved from the body of the question.*

**Fixed:** Added a `z-index: 1;` to `.customnav li ul`.